# discord.js Infinite loop occurs when function is called in response to user's message

Tags: javascript, loops, discord, discord.js, infinite-loop

I am currently working on a Discord bot using JavaScript. The bot is intended to send a randomly generated message when the user says anything from the array:

```
const wordCombos = ["word1","word2","word3","word4"];
```

randomText is the function that produces the randomly generated message, it uses a for loop that randomly adds words from the array to a string. The getRandom function is directly below that.

```
function randomText(out)
{
    var lengthOf = getRandom(2, 6);
    var words = ["random1","random2","random3","random4","random5"];
    var keySmash = "";

    for (var i=0; i < lengthOf; i++)
    {
        var wordsRandom = getRandom(0, words.length);
        keySmash += words[wordsRandom];
    }
    out(keySmash);
}

function getRandom(min, max) 
{
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}
```

When the user sends a message with a word from the array wordCombos, it calls the function. When this occurs the infinite loop begins and the user is spammed with randomly generated messages.

```
client.on('message', msg => 
{
    if(wordCombos.some(word => msg.content.includes(word))) 
    {
        randomText((out) => {msg.channel.send(out);});
    }
});
```

I have tried using a while loop that used a boolean, however the program would either only run one time or cause an infinite loop again.

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/HLUJntl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing that may be causing your code to run like that is your bot is also responding to the messages it sends to itself. To clear that up, you should add this code `if (message.author.bot) return;` right after the beginning section of the code, so then it acts as a filter.

```
client.on('message', msg => 
{
    //message.author.bot returns a boolean
    //true if the user who posted is the bot, else it returns false
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if(wordCombos.some(word => msg.content.includes(word))) 
    {
        randomText((out) => {msg.channel.send(out);});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to complete PerplexingParadox's response I think you should just use includes() in your condition like this :

```
if (wordCombos.includes(msg.content)) 
{
    randomText((out) => {msg.channel.send(out);});
}
```

It will be the same I think. :)

Comment: I originally tried this, but it only works if you put in one of the words from the array and nothing else.